# 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have been trying to implement a way to upload multiple images but I keep getting a managementform error. My way of uploading multiple images was to have the images their own table. And then just use a foreign key for every posts in the page. The problem occurs whenever I go to my create post page

These are my code.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from PIL import Image

import os

# Create your models here.
class Projects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='files/', blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', height_field =                  
    'img_height', width_field = 'img_width',blank=True)
    img_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=600)
    img_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Generates a random string 
        unique_string = get_random_string(length=32)

        # Combines title and unique string to slugify
        slugtext = self.title + "-" + "unique_id=-" + unique_string
        self.slug = slugify(slugtext)

        return super(Projects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_p_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.p_post.title
    slug_title = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug_slug, filename)

class P_Images(models.Model):
    p_post = models.ForeignKey(Projects, default=None,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    p_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_p_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Image')
```

Views.py

```
def create_projects(request):
P_ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(P_Images,form=P_ImageForm,
extra=3)
# Special case if the request method is not POST
if request.method != "POST":
    project_form = ProjectsForm()
    p_formset = P_ImageFormSet(queryset=P_Images.objects.none())

    # No more special case ^ from here
    project_form = ProjectsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    p_formset = P_ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
    queryset=P_Images.objects.all())

    # Checks if the form is valid before save
    if project_form.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid():
        instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
        #if instance.images:

            ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue()))
        instance.save()

        for p_form in p_formset.cleaned_data:
            p_image = p_form['p_image']
            photo = Images(p_post=project_form, p_image=p_image)
            photo.save()

        return render(request, 'projects/forms.html', context)
    #else:
    #    print(project_form.errors, p_formset.errors)

        # Return to the main page
    context = {
        'project_form': project_form,
        'p_formset': p_formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/forms.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Projects, P_Images

class ProjectsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ('images','title', 'description', 'files')


class P_ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = P_Images
        fields = ('p_image',)
```

forms.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!--{{ project_form.as_p }}-->
    {% for hidden in project_form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in project_form %}
    {{ field }} <br />
    {% endfor %}

    {{ p_formset.management_form }}
    {% for p_form in p_formset %}
        {{ p_form }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

This is my full traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/personalwebsite/projects/views.py", line 52, in create_projects
    return render(request, 'projects/forms.html', context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 993, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 676, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 802, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 72, in __getitem__
    return self.forms[index]
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 136, in forms
    for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 110, in total_form_count
    return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 92, in management_form
    code='missing_management_form',
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Comment: you are initializing the var p_formset twice, one with queryset and the other one with form.post,
comment this one out to see if the error is gone
    p_formset = P_ImageFormSet(queryset=P_Images.objects.none())

Comment: @matiasm77 I still have the same error :( I have that piece of code to set the default value of p_formset if the method request is POST

Comment: when you say if request.method != 'POST', that means you are using GET, at this stage you are just showing things, you are not looking for user data, right? if that is the case, the formset can't receive request.POST because it still does not exists, so, management form is not set the way its supposed to...
the first time you set the formset to the queryset to get that, that makes managementform set for many new forms in the formset to display the queryset, but in the same if condition != 'POST' you set it again to request.POST, is the data in , you should print request.POST it will be empty

Comment: @matiasm77 wait sorry man my code got messed up when I posted it. The second p_formset was supposed to be indented. I got it fixed now by not using request.POST. My new error now is that project_form is being referenced before assignment. Thank you man!